# Vertical Scrolling page with Arrow in the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a single page website. I am using scrollify by lukehaas. 
I have five different section in my page. I recently added an arrow in bottom of the first section. The arrow only scrolls down each section by section and when it reaches the last section. I want that arrow to disappear.

HTML

```
<section id="one">
   <a href="#0" class="arrow-down"></a>
</section>

<section id="two">
</section>

<section id="three">
</section>

<section id="four">
</section>

<section id="five">
</section>
```

CSS

```
.arrow-down {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-left: 20px solid transparent;
border-right: 20px solid transparent;

border-top: 20px solid rgba(40,46,106,0.7);
position: fixed;
z-index: 99;
bottom: 2%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Okay, i want to add a css property with jquery when the scrolling reaches to the section five.

Comment: I tried using $(window).height() But i am not able to think any possible way to get to that last section. Would scrollTop come handy this situtation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website of [luke haas](http://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#options) shows that you can define a callback for after the plugin is done scrolling to a section. This callback will recieve the index of the scrolled to section and the array of sections. So what you could do is define a callback that checks if the plugin scrolled to the last element, and if so call `.hide()` on your arrow.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dyr36896/3/)

Hope this helps you.

**--EDIT--**

For a better user experience I suggest you use before instead of after. 'Before' is immediately called after the scroll, before the animation. 'After' is called after the scroll, after the animation. The animation takes a while so you are better of hiding the arrow using the 'before' callback.

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dyr36896/5/)

Comment: `var bottomHeight = $(window).height * 3;
                    if(scrollTop > bottomHeight){
                            $('.arrow-down').hide();
                    }`
Something like this ? but does not work.

Comment: Why would you write your own code when scrollify can handle it for you? I edited the jsfiddle, when you scroll down to the bottom of the javascript you will see the code i wrote.

Comment: Because I am learing. Well, I really am not understanding how scrollify is handling that.

Comment: deleted scrollify source from jsfiddle and added a cdn instead. New jsfiddle link is in the answer.

Comment: Everything you need to know is explained on the website.

Comment: @umangashrestha If this answer helped you out, please accept it.